# Rails - combine multiple has_many throughs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through, arel

I'm just started with Rails, and have a problem I can't solve myself:

**User.rb:**

```
has_many :bid_listings, through: :bids, source: :listing, uniq: true          
has_many :offer_listings, through: :offers, source: :listing, uniq: true
```

Both of these return listings, and using methods/scopes from Listing model individually works perfectly. However, when I'm trying to combine these, I'm getting an Array, where i can't apply Listing model's methods and scopes.

I've tried multiple ways, but stuck. Please help.

P.S. User has many bids, User has many offers, bid belongs to listing, offer belongs to listing

Comment: How are you combining them? And are you sure you're calling the methods and scopes off listing objects? Include some output

Comment: For example: i have a scope on listing that works being applied to bid_listings or offer_listings, ex:

bid_listings.search('something')

However, when I'm trying to concat results of bid_listings + offer_listings - i'm getting an Array.

I've tried to create relation using finder_sql and UNION but without success.

Comment: Include the code you're writing that's failing and the error output as part of the question - easier to see something you're perhaps overlooking.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/5bb7725fbc81a38d6810

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling an instance method on an Array object, as opposed to on an ActiveRecord object. Therefore, object of type Array has no idea what the search method is. Try this out:

**Edit**

```
user = User.first
listings = Listing.joins(:bids).joins(:offers).where(:bids => {:user_id => user.id}, :offers => {:user_id => user.id})
listings.search('a')
```

Comment: That's another relation on different foreign_key, can't use that way :)

Comment: User could be a buyer for listing, and could be a seller. User.listings would return listings he sells, whether user.bid_listings and user.offer_listings return listings where he placed his bid or left an offer to seller

Comment: What about situation when i need this as scope, and user is unknown?

Comment: First, scopes are typically not variable (you don't pass params into them). Second, if you don't know the user, doesn't that mean you want to be searching all listings - Listing.all.search('a')?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, and the best solution I came up with was something like:

```
def buying_listings
  Listing.find_by_sql(bid_listings.union(offer_listings).to_sql)
end
```

This way should still allow you continue scoping, but is less efficient as it will execute an extra query.